# UI-Grid importing losing leading zeros

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using UI-GRID. I am importing data from CSV file. However preceding zeros from numbers are removed automatically. Can somebody help me retain leading zeros? If zeros appear before string they are preserved.

Grid is made as below

```
    vm.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
          { displayName: 'Code', width: '**', field: 'Code', enableColumnMoving: false, hide: false },
          { displayName: 'Name', width: '**', field: 'Name', enableColumnMoving: false, hide: false }
        ],
        enableSorting: false,
        enableColumnMenus: false,
        gridMenuShowHideColumns: false,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        exporterCsvFilename: 'myFile.csv',
        exporterCsvLinkElement: angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location")),
        exporterMenuPdf: false,
        exporterMenuVisibleData: false,

        importerDataAddCallback: function (grid, newObjects) {
            vm.gridOptions.data = newObjects;
        },
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {

           vm.gridApi = gridApi;
        }
    };
```

Comment: you should post the code you are using to do this, otherwise probably we can only guess.

Comment: Code is posted. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in javascript can't have leading zeros. The library is correct. If you want to have leading zeros, you need to declare the column as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How to define a column as string in UI-Grid

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/ set the filter to 'text'.

Comment: I am using UI-GRID and not ag-grid

Answer (score 0):

`ui-grid` internally uses `csv-js` to parse data, which by default converts number with leading zeros(e.g. 0001) to pure number(e.g. 1).

Еo avoid the same, use below code in your js file:

```
CSV.DETECT_TYPES = false;
```

For more info visit:
https://github.com/gkindel/CSV-JS